# How to define column in database having multiple values referenced in another table?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I working on a website, some of the features are similar to Stackoverflow.

One of them is it has multiple items of a type(in SO assume, multiple question).

Each item is related to multiple values of another type(City).(In SO assume, each queston is related to multiple tags. a tag is entry from a table say Tags).

Hence my tables are:

```sql
Cities(Id, Name, IsAcive)
MyItems(Id, DisplayText, AciveInCities)
```

Here one `myitems` entry can be active in multiple cities.

**My question is** how should I define `AciveInCities` column in database. A comma separated CityIds or comma separated city names or some where in different table?

This is a web application where I would like to user be able to search MyItems by cities. Hence saving cityname/id in same table could be fast.

Are there any problems with any of these three approaches?

If this is duplicate question please redirect me to correct one, I could not find one.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You shouldn't have multi-valued columns in your database - it is not [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Have a many-to-many table with `CityId` and `ItemId` columns as foreign keys and which together are a composite primary key.

```
Cities(Id, Name, IsAcive)
MyItems(Id, DisplayText)
ItemsActiveInCities(CityId, ItemId)
```

Comment: This is good. But why I wanted to have them in same table was for speed in search operation. As many of the searches will be using cities.

Comment: @Maheep - You have a misconception here. Having them in one field will be _slower_, as you will need to parse it, order it and still join on the results. Having it in a separate table is the correct relational design. When it comes to speed - you need to measure and find bottlenecks, not guess at where they may happen.

Answer (score 4):

A third associative table would be the normalized approach:

```
City
(CityId, Name, IsAcive)

Item
(ItemId, DisplayText)

ItemActiveInCity
(ItemId, CityId)
```

---

As to why storing comma separated values in a database column is not a good idea, see this: [Is storing a comma separated list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-comma-separated-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad)

Comment: This is good. But why I wanted to have them in same table was for speed in search operation. As many of the searches will be using cities.

Comment: Read the answer by Bill Karwin in the link I added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the words would say **not recommended**, as intersection of row/col is suppose to be **one cell**, so what if you made another column that represent that, 
**for example** if my project is a library and my task is to List the names of customers who have bought "Math for elementary students" AND "Explanation of Sahih Muslim" in a **SINGLE** order.

That means I need a list of books(IDS) in a single order.

**solution** :

Define a Column like the orderID (the primary key ), yet allows repeatition, 
that **simply** will allow you to **combine** those rows later.